# GetAsyncKeyState() not working, making a console game

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a c++ console game - there is a map with '#' as a border and a '@' itside which can be moved via keyboard. But when a press the button, nothing happens... Can't figure out what might have caused this behaviour.

```
      #include <iostream>
      #include <windows.h>

      using namespace std;

        char Map[10][10]={  "#########", 
                               "#       #",  
                                 "#       #",
                                "#       #",
                                 "#       #",
                                 "#       #",
                                "#       #",
                                 "#       #",
                                "#@      #",
                                 "#########"};

     int Gamespeed=100;
     int lvl=0;
     bool stopgame=false;


  int main()
  {
    while (stopgame==false)
    {
            system("cls");
            for (int y=0; y<10; y++)
            {
                cout<<Map[y]<<endl; //rows
    }


    for (int y=0; y<10; y++)   //rows
        for (int x=0; x<10; x++)   //columns
                {
                        switch (Map[y][x])
                        {
                        case '@':
                            {  cout<<"@ here";
                                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)!=0)
                                {   cout<<"Key up";
                                    int y2=y-1;
                                    switch (Map[y2][x])
                                    {
                                    case ' ':
                                        {
                                            Map[y][x]=' ';
                                            y--;
                                            Map[y][x]='@';
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)!=0)
                                {
                                            switch (Map[y+1][x])
                                                {
                                                case ' ':
                                                    {
                                                            Map[y][x]=' ';
                                                            y++;
                                                            Map[y][x]='@';
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                }

                                }

                                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)!=0)
                                {
                                    switch (Map[y][x+1])
                                    {
                                    case ' ':
                                        {
                                            Map[y][x]=' ';
                                            x++;
                                            Map[y][x]='@';
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)!=0)
                                {
                                    switch (Map[y][x-1])
                                    {
                                    case ' ':
                                        {
                                            Map[y][x]=' ';
                                            x--;
                                            Map[y][x]='@';
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                }






return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The correct way to test if a key is down is `if (GetAsyncKeyState(...) < 0)`. As for what's wrong with the logic of your code, it's very hard to read due to the indentation. Do you really indent your code like that? Have you considered debugging your program? If you don't know what that means then you need to stop writing more code and start learning how to debug. Any other activity is simply a waste of your time.

Comment: It's not really my code, I'm just playing around with the code from this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfRjvvgjTNQ&list=PLGxFit7OrNc5jjF5rHPZSCaovAw_FvUiI&index=2
My main concern is to study how to handle the keyboard input and make the symbol move, anyway.

Comment: The use of GetAsyncKeyState worries me from a console app. Its part of user 32 and its companion functions all deal with the keystate managed by the message loop.

Comment: @parsecer If you aren't interested in understanding and debugging the code yourself, why would we be? It feels to me like you aren't committed enough to understand your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, bad formatting and code style, but for me it is working if you add close brace for `while` cycle:

```
int main()
{
    while (stopgame == false)
    {
        // your code here
    } // <- you don't have this brace
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's called a "loop".

Comment: I think it's reasonably clear that the question doesn't contain the actual code. If it did, it would be indented properly, and would have the right number of braces.